# Split file into multiple files based on field

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

How am I able to split a file into multiple files based on `$2`?

Example of input,

```
123,hello,world
124,hello,planet
125,universe,hello
126,hello,universe
```

Desired output,

```
hello.txt >

123,hello,world
124,hello,planet
126,hello,universe

universe.txt >

125,universe,hello
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{name=$2 ".txt"; print >>name; close(name)}' FS=',' file
```

---

A very similar question at stackoverflow.com: [split file by lines and keep the first string as a header for output files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63527318/3776858)

Comment: Opening and closing each file for every line is seriously inefficient. GNU/awk will handle about 1024 open files concurrently. (It actually handles any number, but behind the scenes it closes a random one to keep the number currently open below 1024.) Best safe strategy is probably to keep a hash of the names in use, and close all the files when the number open gets too large. Timed optimum is to load up a million input lines at once, and then write all the lines for one file at a time, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Here's an earlier question about pretty much exactly the same thing, along with a few answers and some discussion on their ups and downs: [awk how to separate in different files all the lines with the same content in a given column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/603851/170373)